# Can i Run Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators on Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-server-2008, virtualization, windows-phone-8-emulator

Is it possible to run the Emulator in a VM with Server 2008 R2?

I have a Win Server 2008 R2 running on a VM.
How can i install the Windows Phone 8.1 emulators and run them?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx -- System requirements for the emulator for Windows Phone 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run an Emulator in a VM. Running a VM (emulator) in an other VM is not supported.